# Finding the non singular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$(1)$  Suppose $A$ and $B$ satisfy the relation $B^2+AB+2I=0$. Are the following four matrices necessarily non singular?

(a)$A$   ( b)$B$        (c) $A+2I$             (d) $B+2I$

My attempt:-                      $$B^2+AB+2I=0$$
                                  $$\Rightarrow B^2+AB= -2I$$
                                  $$\Rightarrow B(A+B)= -2I$$
                                  $$\Rightarrow |B(A+B)|= |-2I|$$
                                     $$\Rightarrow |B||A+B|= (-2)^3|I|=-8$$
So, $$|B|\not= 0$$
Reqd. Answer is $B$.
Am I Correct?

Comment: How did you end up with $\det (-2I) = -8$? Are you presuming that the matrices are $3 \times 3$?

Comment: I apologize. Actually, I presumed it to be a $3\times 3$ matrix. However, in the question, no information is provided about the order of $A$, $B$(Obviously they should be of same order), so it should be $|-2I|=(-2)^n$  ($n$ being the order of $A$, $B$ and $I$)

Comment: Once you have $B(A+B)=-2I$ you already have that $B^{-1}=-\frac{1}{2}(A+B)$. No determinant is necessary, nor knowing the size of the matrices (they must be square of the same size anyhow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that $B$ has to be invertible. Let's construct an example which shows the matrices $A$, $A + 2I$ and $B + 2I$ can be singular.

$B$ is invertible so we can express $A$ from $B^2 + AB + 2I = 0$ as $$A = B + 2B^{-1}$$

Using the Spectral theorem, we conclude that the eigenvalues of $A$ are of the form $x + \frac2x$, where $x \in \sigma(B)$.

$A$ is singular if and only if $0\in \sigma(A)$ so $$0  = x + \frac2x \iff x = \pm i\sqrt{2}$$

Meaning $\pm i\sqrt{2} \in \sigma (B)$.

On the other hand, $A + 2I$ is singular if and only if $-2 \in \sigma(A)$, which happens when

$$-2 = x + \frac2x \iff x = -1 \pm i$$

So it has to be $-1 \pm i \in \sigma(B)$.

Now, setting $B = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2}i & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -2 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1 + i \end{pmatrix}$ yields $$A = B + 2B^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -3 & 0\\0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$

so $A, A + 2I$ and $B + 2I$ are all singular.

Therefore, $(b)$ is the only correct option.

Interestingly, the above discussion also shows that  $A, A + 2I$ and $B + 2I$ cannot all simultaneously be singular if the matrices are $2 \times 2$ since then $\sigma(B)$ can have at most two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If $B$ were singular there would be some nonzero vector $v$ such that $Bv=0$, but then
$$(B^2+AB+2I)v=0$$
$$\implies 2Iv=0$$
$$\implies v=0$$
which contradicts the assumption that $v$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose $A=0$, $B= \sqrt{2}i I$, so $A$ could be singular.

You could choose $A=-2I$, $B=(1+i)I$, so $A+2I$ could be singular.

You could choose $B=-2I$, $A=3I$, so $B+2I$ could be singular.